# How to override read-only files with "compass compile" command?

Tags: sass, file-permissions, compass-sass

I have MS Visual Studio web project folder came from TFS server with several *.scss files and already generated *.css (by Mindscape Web Workbench Visual Studio plug-in).

Before publishing site want to regenerate *.css files using Compass.
But files *.css files are included in project and checked in, so they are marked with **read-only** file attribute.

My command line:

```
C:\Ruby193\bin>compass compile
   --force
   --sass-dir 'd:\SDesign'
   --css-dir 'd:\SDesign' 
   --output-style compressed
   --no-line-comments
   --relative-assets
   --trace
```

and here is the result:

```
overwrite Style.css
Errno::EACCES on line ["56"] of C: Permission denied - d:/SDesign/Style.css
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/actions.rb:56:in `open'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/actions.rb:56:in `write_file'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:144:in `compile'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:118:in `compile_if_required'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `each'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `block in run'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:100:in `run'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:45:in `perform'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:43:in `call'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:43:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/Ruby193/bin/compass:19:in `load'
  C:/Ruby193/bin/compass:19:in `<main>'
```

Is there any way to not reset read-only attribute from target *.css files manually?
Maybe some *magic* command parameter?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my temporary solution.
If you know the way better please tell me!

```
@echo off
set ruby_bin=c:\Ruby193\bin
set project_path=d:\CDesign
set temp_path=%project_path%\temp

if exist "%temp_path%" rd "%temp_path%" /Q /S
mkdir "%temp_path%"

call %ruby_bin%\compass.bat compile --force --sass-dir '%project_path%' --css-dir '%temp_path%' --output-style compressed --no-line-comments --relative-assets

xcopy %temp_path%\*.* %project_path% /S /R /Y
rd "%temp_path%" /Q /S
```